# Using CSS-Element-Queries Library to simulate CSS's media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used this seemingly fancy [CSS-Element-Queries tool](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/) for some basic element manipulations that will be started every time a window is resized.

Briefly, I wanted to change the value of an element's attribute based on current window width i.e. *every time when the window is somehow resized I want to check its width and subsequently do something with a certain element*.

I did everything like it is in the tutorial but something must be wrong since it is not working at all. Here is the code:

```
<script src="css-element-queries/src/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
<script src="css-element-queries/src/ElementQueries.js"></script>

<script>
    new ResizeSensor(jQuery(window), function(){ 
        var a = $(window).width();

        if (a < 1024 && a > 768) {
            $(".slideshow").attr("data-cycle-carousel-visible", 4);
        }
        if (a <= 768 && a > 480) {
            $(".slideshow").attr("data-cycle-carousel-visible", 3);
        }
        if ((a <= 480) && (a > 320)) {
            $(".slideshow").attr("data-cycle-carousel-visible", 2);
        }
        if (a <= 320) {
            $(".slideshow").attr("data-cycle-carousel-visible", 1);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "It is not working" is not a useful problem description. Have you checked that the function is called at all? Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Why not using `.onresize`, `.resize()` or even pure CSS media queries?

Comment: Looking at the example code, you should probably replace `jQuery(window)` with `window`

Comment: Also, are you sure that changing the attribute will have an immediate effect? If the attribute is merely used to initialize the carousel, changing it later might do nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be watching for the window resize, and then call your resizer function on resize.

```
//watch for resize
 $( window ).resize(function() {
   //call function each time window is resized
   resizr();
 });

 var resizr = new ResizeSensor(jQuery(window), function(){ 
    var a = $(window).width();

    if (a < 1024 && a > 768) {
        $(".slideshow").attr("data-cycle-carousel-visible", 4);
    }
    if (a <= 768 && a > 480) {
        $(".slideshow").attr("data-cycle-carousel-visible", 3);
    }
    if ((a <= 480) && (a > 320)) {
        $(".slideshow").attr("data-cycle-carousel-visible", 2);
    }
    if (a <= 320) {
        $(".slideshow").attr("data-cycle-carousel-visible", 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a completely manual solution; it doesn't need `ResizeSensor()` on top, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You have nothing watching for the actual resize. That is why it is not working. You have a function that defines what to do on resize, but nothing to actally watch for resize. Adding the jQuery .resize() method will fix that.

Comment: @Korgrue, alright, you have a point. But what is `ResizeSensor` doing there? Just wrapping a bunch of manual window jQuery checks? It has no use, apparently.

Comment: ResizeSensor is your method to eval and define what to do with the element, correct? If its some method from a different framework, then yeah - you can strip it and just give the method a different name.

Comment: Yes, but it should also take care of adding the event listener. That's the whole point.

Comment: It don't seem to be doing that. Using .resize() is cross platform reliable so I would use that rather than whatever the ResizeSensor is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Ok, but why using `ResizeSensor` if jQuery _and_ JavaScript both have this event natively? As Chris said, by using this plugin, you _at least_ shouldn't have to bind a resize event. Cause what's the point of using it, if you'll have to manually do it anyway?

Comment: @Korgrue I agree, but the question isn't about listening to the resize event, it's about how to use the linked library. OP accepted your answer though, so I guess they were looking for any solution that does the trick.

Comment: Unintentional as a workaround. Did not realize that ResizeSensor was a component from a different framework. Assumed that it was just a function name he made up.